# Python3: fast decode bytes to signed integer, special encoding

Tags: python, decode, numpy-ndarray

I have a connection from my PC to a sensor thru an ethernet connection (UDP protocol) that sends me data.
The data looks is a long array of bytes, like this

```
data
Out[260]: b'03000248023003e802a003a002f8044003c80478038802f002d8024002b00258030003a80300035002a803c0031002e802c8030802e001f8029002a003c8045002d803f003100378038002a002d803700308029003e00260032002e0027002c0028002a802e80338036804c803300398'
```

This data is actually coded, and I want to generate out of it a numpy.ndarray made of signed integers. One data sample per ndarray element.
Each array element once decoded represents an ADC data sample: 12bit + sign integer.
The coding is the following: the bytes must be grouped by 4. Each byte actually represent an hexa number. Then the 4 hexa numbers are put together, divided by 8 and we take the 2's complement.

The code I use so far works fine is below:

```
 j = 0
 while j < nb_sample:    # loop on each adc data sample
        adc_sample_str = chr(udp_frame[4*j]) + chr(udp_frame[4*j+1]) + chr(udp_frame[4*j+2]) + chr(udp_frame[4*j+3])    # create the sample by concatenating 4 hexadecimals characters (2 bytes)
        adc_sample_int = int(adc_sample_str, 16)    # convert into hexa number
        adc_sample_int = (adc_sample_int >> 3)      # right shift by 3 (divide by 8)
        if adc_sample_int > 2047:                   # check if it is a negative value (2048 = 0b 0000 1000 0000 0000)
                adc_sample_int = (adc_sample_int - (2*4096) + 1)    # 2's complement

        result[j] = adc_sample_int    
        j+=1
```

The big problem is this loop is super slow.

So I am looking for another more clever way that would be much faster (~10x)
So I've tried a lot of things: convert to a string with .decode('UTF-8') or use numpy.frombuffer with many different dtypes.
But I could not find a coding (dtype) that can read my weird format.

Does anybody know in which direction I should look ?
Maybe I should write a custom-made encoding schemes for the .decode ? But I don't know how to express my coding scheme.
Or shall I rather convert to a string? But then ...?
All I tried so far makes me run into circle.
Any hint would help me...
Thanks

The result of the loop code is the following:

```
result[0:260]
Out[268]: 
array([ 96,  73,  70, 125,  84, 116,  95, 136, 121, 143, 113,  94,  91,
        72,  86,  75,  96, 117,  96, 106,  85, 120,  98,  93,  89,  97,
        92,  63,  82,  84, 121, 138,  91, 126,  98, 111, 112,  84,  91,
       110,  97,  82, 124,  76, 100,  92,  78,  88,  80,  85,  93, 103,
       109, 153, 102, 115,  89, 134, 105, 108,  84, 100,  76, 101,  81,
        96,  98, 106,  98, 116, 109,  98,  93, 118, 111,  94,  95,  98,
        91, 141,  76,  97, 110,  92, 104, 103,  89,  86, 101,  85, 114,
        82,  83, 104,  72, 103, 118,  92, 133, 111, 104,  85, 101,  92,
       108, 108, 108, 100,  81, 102,  99, 102, 125, 121,  68,  75, 104,
        85,  90,  96, 127, 102, 112, 118, 106,  92,  78,  98,  98,  96,
       105,  77,  79, 107, 100,  88,  89, 115,  86,  98, 106, 100, 105,
        79, 121, 109, 115,  80, 113,  84, 131,  91, 114, 126,  93,  95,
       119,  73, 100, 121, 102,  98, 100, 117, 111,  63,  99,  97, 108,
       109,  95,  75, 102,  93, 127, 112,  91,  86,  79,  68, 104, 104,
        84, 116,  85,  79, 120,  95,  91,  75, 135, 116, 115, 119, 102,
        90, 131,  57, 102,  86, 104,  99, 106,  97,  95, 116, 116, 123,
        99,  87,  61, 105,  81, 104,  91, 108, 114,  82, 122,  84, 108,
       107,  93, 101,  95,  76,  84,  74, 104, 113, 110, 104, 123,  91,
        99, 120,  92, 107, 120,  97, 119,  76,  87, 118,  73,  85, 113,
       104, 123,  99,  94, 101,  97, 103,  65, 103])
```

Comment: Is the example bytestring a `udp_frame`?, What is `result`? And what should `nb_sample` be for the example data ?

Comment: Your example data has 224 *characters* and the expected array has 256 items - that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Link to your sensor docs?

Comment: The input data is indeed an udp frame. Result is a ndarray (normally 2D, I simplified here for readibiity) of the data matrix after decoding. During the copy/paste to show the code, I simplified and did not use exactly the right number of bytes, sorry. The real data is around 1000 bytes long. I don't have a real doc for the sensor. But the micro controller is an S32R274 from NXP. I've got the code from a friend of mine. I might change it if needed, but I'm not an expert in MCU micro-coding...

Answer (score 0):

you didn't provide a complete minimal reproducable question, so i improvised somewhat to make your provided code work.

```py
data = b"03000248023003e802a003a002f8044003c80478038802f002d8024002b00258030003a80300035002a803c0031002e802c8030802e001f8029002a003c8045002d803f003100378038002a002d803700308029003e00260032002e0027002c0028002a802e80338036804c803300398"
from numpy import array
import numpy as np


def func(data):
    nb_sample = len(data) // 4
    udp_frame = data
    result = array(range(nb_sample))
    j = 0
    while j < nb_sample:  # loop on each adc data sample
        adc_sample_str = (
            chr(udp_frame[4 * j])
            + chr(udp_frame[4 * j + 1])
            + chr(udp_frame[4 * j + 2])
            + chr(udp_frame[4 * j + 3])
        )  # create the sample by concatenating 4 hexadecimals characters (2 bytes)
        adc_sample_int = int(adc_sample_str, 16)  # convert into hexa number
        adc_sample_int = adc_sample_int >> 3  # right shift by 3 (divide by 8)
        if (
            adc_sample_int > 2047
        ):  # check if it is a negative value (2048 = 0b 0000 1000 0000 0000)
            adc_sample_int = adc_sample_int - (2 * 4096) + 1  # 2's complement
        result[j] = adc_sample_int
        j += 1
    return result


def func4(data):
    for j in range(len(data) // 4):
        adc_sample = int(data[4 * j : 4 * j + 4], 16) >> 3
        if adc_sample > 2047:
            adc_sample -= 2 * 2096 + 1
        yield adc_sample


def func5(data):
    result = np.fromiter(func4(data), int)
    return result
```

these are the results i got with the timeit module

```py
>>> import timeit
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def avg(seq): return sum(seq) / len(seq)
...
>>> avg(timeit.repeat(partial(func, data), number=10_000))
0.9369430501999887
>>> avg(timeit.repeat(partial(func5, data), number=10_000))
0.3753632108000602
```

### edit:

so i am somewhat new to numpy. in my original code there was a mistake,
to create a numpy array from a generator you should use `np.fromiter` instead of `np.array`
i had a problem in my tests that resulted in me not spotting the invalid func5.

fixing the code lead to drastic performance decreases,
*func5 is now only about twice as fast as func*, and i think that most of that performance gain is from a restructuring of the inner loop.
things like using data[j:j+4] in stead of data[j] + data[j+1] + data[j+2] + data[j+3]

I also was also mistaken about when to use generators,
Generators are more about space performance than time performance.
it might still be a good idea for your application, but that is out of scope for this question

Comment: `assert np.all(func5()==func())`? or `np.all(np.isclose(func(),func5()))`

Comment: Thanks a lot steviestickman. First time I hear about the concept of generator ! That seems very powerful. Can you help me understand how to use the 2 functions ? why are you not giving any arguments to func4 and func5 functions ? How shall I call func5 ?

Comment: Can somebody please tell me how to use the func4 and func5 functions ? So far I always get error messages....

Comment: @steviestickman ok, for the data, I got it. But regarding how to call the func5...I'm lost !

Comment: ok, thanks @steviestickman now with the new code it works ! I get around x5 speedup factor. Not too bad ! To go even faster, I thought of getting rid of the for loop, by using .frombuffer, but I need to describe my data forat. Any idea how to describe my format ?

Comment: see the [numpy reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) and [format caracters from struct](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#format-characters). 16bit signed integer = "h", string of length 4 = "4S"

Comment: I tried to do np.frombuffer(data,dtype='4S') and got an array of bytes, grouped by 4. But then to convert the bytes to integer I tried .astype(int) but this only converts to base 10 integer. I did not find a solution to convert to base 16 integer. Almost there, but not yet quite ! Any idea?

Comment: you could try np.from_stream(map(lambda n: int(n, 16), buffer))